# Akka Performance issue

Tags: java, performance, akka, cascading

I have written an Akka application to have 10 actors to execute my custom code (ie., read the data from a file row by row, apply some functions, and write the data into output file).

When I execute the code in tomcat, the performance degrades when the number of actors is higher than 4.

If I execute the same code as a "Run AS JAVA Application" then the performance is good.

Is there any configuration that I am missing when I run Akka code in tomcat? Please help me fix this performance issue. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what limits the performance of your application you can try to use some profiler, for example visual vm. You can look to the threads panel and see what threads utilised by actors and what threads are tomcat-born, what are hot threads/methods/lines of code.. This should give you some idea on the threads usage and weak places in your application. Also you should get an idea of the type of "boundness" of your code - most probably it is cpu or io bound.

Based on the knowledge acquired earlier, you should be able to make some optimizations of the code.

Possible directions are:

- io related optimizations (threads usage, bufferring). I would recommend you to look to [akka-streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/stream/index.html) way of working with streaming data like data from csv file. There is a special chapter in [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/stream/stream-io.html) on that.
- algorithmic optimizations of your functions.
- tweaking resources usage of akka actors. You probably want to be aware of when working with akka actors is a dispatcher settings. Basically the dispatcher manages the thread pool and binds actors to it. You can read the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html) on that.